# C# library for Windows Process Management

Tags: windows, library, c#, logs, performance-analysis

It seems there are libraries out there for anything these days! I need to develop a program that will spawn a couple of Windows programs and need to monitor:

- That they are still alive
- Any log files that they create
- StdIn, StdOut, StdErr (if any)
- Performance metrics (Disk, IO, Network, CPU)

Is there a "ready made" library out there that will do the legwork for me?

I'm aware that I can use WMI Performance Counters, Tracing, System.Diagnostics etc. to do the above, but I'm hoping that someone clever has already developed a kickass library for dealing with the low level stuff.

I'm not against paying for the software, so paid/open/closed are all acceptable, however free is better than paid, and open is better than closed.

---

Update: I originally posted this on Stack Overflow and got advised to re-post here.

Update 2: After a long time searching online I came up with these candidate process libraries, but none seem what im looking for:

- PS Interop - https://psinterop.codeplex.com/ (Not quite right)
- ChildProcesses - https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChildProcesses/ (For managing your own sub processes, I need to manage external ones)

Update 3: Neither of the above seem to really do the trick. I guess I'm gonna have to roll my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you just use the .NET framework directly.

- That they are still alive

The [Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object has a [HasExited](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.hasexited%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to determine this.

- Any log files that they create

This is an ackward one it depeneds on how the application logs.  If they create files monitor the files they create maybe using [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.  If they are event logs you need to know how they log to the event log.  If they write to standard output (stdout) look at the [RedirectStandardOutput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property documentation.

- StdIn, StdOut, StdErr (if any)

This is all available from the [Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object.

- Performance metrics (Disk, IO, Network, CPU)

This can be done with [PerformanceCounter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

But there is also wolfpack https://wolfpack.codeplex.com/

> Project Description Wolfpack aims to be the "swiss army knife" of
>   monitoring. To borrow a line from Etsy..."if it moves we monitor it,
>   even if it doesn't move we'll monitor it just in case it makes a break
>   for it!".

You may need to write a plugin for your specifics but this might just work out of the box for you with some configuration.

**Features**

- IIS logs
  -Firewall logs
- Event logs (including queries that join to those on remote machines)
- Many other textual logging formats such as CSV, XML (including making an http call to retrieve the data, eg: RSS, Webservice)
- FileSystem
- Sql Server data (write queries to detect any sort of data condition eg: monitor for orders > £value or not despatched after N
  days)
- MSMQ
- RabbitMQ (contrib plugin)
- Windows Services
- Web service/site Ping
- System (CPU, Disk) utilisation
- Build/CI (TeamCity at the moment) and the extraction of stats from common build tools like NCover, SpecFlow, StoryQ
- Deployment - Wolfpack can automatically deploy NuGet packages - these can contain your entire website/application or just some unit
  tests and Wolfpack will detect, download and unpack it, even running
  the unit tests and sending a notifcation with the results in!
- SSL Certificate expiry - monitor for certificates getting close to expiry and stop embarrassing incidents like the one SagePay just
  experienced.